# PIL: Is it possible to fill a mask?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Suppose I have a mask (a blank triangle - 1/255/etc in the triangle, 0 elsewhere) and I have the texture I'd like to place inside that triangle, but the texture is sequential instead of being formatted into an image format. For example, if the box containing the triangle/mask is 100 x 100, but the triangle itself only has 2500 pixels, I only have the information for the 2500 pixels instead of having the actual box.

So, I could fill the triangle manually, either doing each row or column at a time, but I was wondering if there was a method to do this instead.

Here's the code I used anyways:

```
def fill_mask(mask, data): #mask and data are ndarrays
    mask = np.copy(mask).T
    k = 0
    for i in xrange(len(mask)):
        for j in xrange(len(mask[i])):
            if mask[i][j] == 1:
                mask[i][j] = data[k]
                k += 1
    return mask.T
```

That one fills horizontally (line by line). To fill vertically, take away the `.T` in the first and last lines. It can probably be made shorter though I'm awful with that so I'll just leave it as it is. Any improvements to it are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mask[mask==1] = data`

Comment: This is even better than what I wanted, thanks! I just have to transpose it at the right times to change the way it's filled.

Comment: @chimichanga: if `mask` is a boolean array then it could be even `v[mask] = data`, where `v=np.zeros(mask.shape,data.dtype)`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking if you can fill/modify each pixel of the triangle using an array of values without also having to visit the pixels which you don't want to fill using only the image data.

If that's so, then the short answer is no.

Certainly it would be possible to create some optimization array that only referenced those pixels which were part of the triangle, but in order to create that array, you'd have to visit each pixel, so it would only be a savings if you have to visit the same set many times.

PIL probably provides some helpers to do blending that might be optimized, which would be better than trying to roll your own.

If on the other hand, you know the dimensions and position of the triangle in your mask, you could calculate the position of the pixels inside the triangle. For that you'll need to study your trigonometry.

**If you don't know how to do this already, I'd say stick with visiting each pixel, it will be a good learning experience. If you need to improve performance later, the path will be clearer once you understand the basic concepts.**